# Выборка из таблицы sql

Tags: sql, база-данных

Можно ли сделать выборку данных из таблицы по мере возрастания значении ID?

Comment: Что именно вы подразумеваете под фразой __"по мере возрастания значении ID"__. Если отсортировать, то поле ID обрабатывается точно так же, как и любое другое.

Comment: Если это вопрос о возможности - да, можно. Если о допустимости - да, можно, делайте.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если тебе нужно, чтобы строки шли от минимальной значениния (например 1) к максимальному (например 10), то есть: 1, 2, 3, 4 и тд, то

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `id`
```

А если наоборот, 10, 9, 8, 7 и так до 1, то

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!